# Single "mkdir" command to make a new directory and change to that directory at the same time?

Tags: linux, mkdir

**Quick question:**

Is it possible to use "mkdir" to make a new directory AND change to that directory at the same time using a single 'mkdir' command?

**Whole question:**

I have this question:

```
What single Linux “mkdir” command could replace the sequence of commands?
         mkdir a
         cd a
         mkdir b
         cd b
         mkdir c
         cd ../..
```

My answer is:

```
         mkdir a b c && cd c
```

Is there a single "mkdir" command, without using any other commands, perhaps with some flags or something, I can use to make AND change directory at the same time?

Comment: And https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125385/combined-mkdir-and-cd ...

Comment: Your question title and your question body don't match.  The question body says (paraphrased) can I combine these three `mkdir` commands into a single `mkdir` command? If you understood the list of six commands (which, apparently, you don't), you would see that you end up in the top-level directory where you started.

Comment: I believe that this question has been misinterpreted and closed incorrectly.  (OK, it probably is a duplicate, but not of any of the questions linked here.) [Filipe Brandenburger's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/483369/80216#483371) is the right answer to *this* question.

Comment: @G-Man dupe of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84191/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49263/recursive-mkdir then?

Comment: @muru: Yes, those.

Comment: @Stephen can you edit the duplicates list to include one of these two as well?

Comment: Have you tested your answer? Does it work?

Comment: Yeah, I misread the question completely and misunderstood the ../.., thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you present of using a single `mkdir` command to do the same as the other steps doesn't really involve changing directories. It ends with `cd ../..` which brings you back to the directory you were in at the start.

In effect, that sequence of commands creates a directory `a`, then a directory `b` within it (in other words, `a/b`), then a directory `c` within the just created `b` (in other words, `a/b/c`.)

You can do the same with a single `mkdir` command that creates the nested directories after creating their parents:

```
mkdir a a/b a/b/c
```

Another way is using `mkdir`'s `-p` option, which will create the parent directories if necessary, so you don't need to specify them:

```
mkdir -p a/b/c
```

This doesn't answer your question in the title (for mkdir + cd look at the duplicates from the comments), but addresses the question in your text, about the equivalent single `mkdir` command for that sequence, in which at the end of the sequence the directory is the same as at the start of it.

Comment: This is the right answer. Of course, I'm a little biased, because it is *remarkably* similar to the answer I just finished typing in Notepad.  Good job on getting it in 25 minutes ahead of me!

Comment: @G-Man Great minds think alike 

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question, oops! Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @G-Man Why are you typing it in notepad? Type it into the shell, see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Do it as a function:

```
mkcdir ()
{
    mkdir -p -- "$1" &&
      cd -P -- "$1"
}
```